# String transfer via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth

We are able to list paired Bluetooth devices in a text view.The app has two EditText ,one to accept string message and the other to accept the MAC address of destination device,and one send button to send the message to the destination address, but the app is getting closed when clicked on the send button.Kindly help us.
Thanks in advance.
         package com.example.javapoint;

```
     import android.os.Bundle;

 import android.app.Activity;  
  import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.Menu;  
   import android.view.View;

    import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
  import java.util.Set; 
 import java.util.UUID;

   import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;  
     import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;  
     import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
   import android.content.Intent;  
    import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;  
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 TextView textview1;  
 UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

 private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;  
 BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    // Getting the Bluetooth adapter  
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();  
    textview1.append("\nAdapter: " + btAdapter);  


        CheckBluetoothState();  

  }  

  /* It is called when an activity completes.*/  
  @Override  
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {  
      CheckBluetoothState();  
    }  
  }  

  @Override  
  protected void onDestroy() {  
    super.onDestroy();  
  }  

  private void CheckBluetoothState() {  
    // Checks for the Bluetooth support and then makes sure it is turned on  
    // If it isn't turned on, request to turn it on  
    // List paired devices  
    if(btAdapter==null) {   
      textview1.append("\nBluetooth NOT supported. Aborting.");  
      return;  
    } else {  
      if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {  
        textview1.append("\nBluetooth is enabled...");  

        // Listing paired devices  
        textview1.append("\nPaired Devices are:");  
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();  
        for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {  
          textview1.append("\n  Device: " + device.getName() + ", " + device);  
        }  
      } else {  
        //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth  
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);  
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);  
      }  
    }  


    Button sbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
final String msg=et.getText().toString();
     final EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.macaddress);
    final String mac=et1.getText().toString();
     sbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {




            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 byte[] toSend = msg.getBytes();


                 try {

                     BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice =    btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mac);
BluetoothSocket socket       =mBluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
                        socket.connect();
    OutputStream mmOutStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                        mmOutStream.write(toSend);
                        socket.close();
    // Your Data is sent to  BT connected paired device ENJOY.
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
            }
        });


    }






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

  }
```

Comment: Exception stacktrace from logcat, please.

Comment: 03-28 02:19:58.160: E/BluetoothAdapter(794): Bluetooth binder is null
03-28 02:19:59.550: D/gralloc_goldfish(794): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-28 02:22:48.401: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-28 02:22:57.651: I/Choreographer(794): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.                              These errors were logged in LogCat

Comment: Please edit the question instead of posting as comments. Look for the `FATAL EXCEPTION`.

Comment: fatal exception not found